# Git Tower warning sign

Tags: git, git-merge

[image]I'm trying to reverse merge the master branch into my local-branch using **TOWER git client**, it has some merge conflicts I have resolved that but still getting warning sign. Attaching the screenshot for better understanding.**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, solving all merge conflicts with tower should lead you to make a commit.
As described in "[Solving Merge Conflicts](https://www.git-tower.com/help/guides/branches-and-tags/merge-conflicts/windows)"

> After having solved all conflicts you must commit your resolution. A suitable merge commit message is automatically prefilled for you.

[image: https://www.git-tower.com/help/media/pages/guides/branches-and-tags/merge-conflicts/windows/-1923132997-1588745906/conflict-step-5.png]

But if you believe you have solved everything, switch to command-line, and do a `git status`: you will see if there is any other files with merge conflicts there.

Answer (score 1):

The warning sign indicates that you are still in a merge. After resolving the merge conflicts, you will need to click on the Commit button to proceed with the merge. If you need further assistance, feel free to reach out to us via support@git-tower.com!